# Paths drawn from the same bounding box have different radii

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas

### Background

I'm drawing a custom `View`, which consists of an arc along which images are drawn.

A bit like this "Wheel of Fortune" screenshot, where only part of a large disc is visible and, as the user drags the view, images become visible/hidden as appropriate and are drawn at the appropriate position and angle along the disc's edge.

[image: Wheel of Fortune]

This works fine; I use the code below to create a large bounding box (four times the width of the view, to get a more subtle arc), which I use with `Path.arcTo()` to draw the visible top edge of the disc.

Because the bounding box is square, the arc drawn (if I were to draw 360°) would be circular.

```java
// Disc dimensions (based on this View's width/height/padding)
final int radius = width * 2;
final float halfWidth = width / 2f;
final float top = mTopPadding;

// Create a large, square bounding box to draw the disc in.
// Centre horizontally; top edge of the disc == top edge of this View (+ padding)
final RectF discBounds = 
    new RectF(-radius + halfWidth, top, radius + halfWidth, radius * 2 + top);

// Create an arc along the circumference of the disc,
// but only where it will intersect with this View
double arcSweep = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(halfWidth / radius)) * 2;
double startAngle = 180 + ((180 - arcSweep) / 2d);
mDiscPath.reset();
mDiscPath.arcTo(discBounds, (float) startAngle, (float) arcSweep);

// Close the shape so that we fill the rest of this View
// (the area underneath the arc) with the disc bg colour
mDiscPath.lineTo(width, height);
mDiscPath.lineTo(0, height);
```

I then create another `Path` and again call `arcTo()`, using the exact same bounding box so that the same arc radius is maintained.

This time the sweep angle of the arc is longer, since there may be only two or three images shown within the `View` at one time, but an arbitrary number of images off-screen (in my case, up to about ten).

```java
// Create another arc, along which the images should move,
// based on the number and width of the images.
// We will later use a PathMeasure object created from
// this Path to determine where to draw each image
arcSweep = (mTotalWidth * 180) / (radius * Math.PI);
startAngle = 180 + ((180 - arcSweep) / 2d);
mImagePath.reset();
mImagePath.arcTo(discBounds, (float) startAngle, (float) arcSweep);
```

---

### Problem

In `onDraw()`, the `mDiscPath` is drawn as the background (`canvas.drawPath(mDiscPath, fillPaint)`), and then the appropriate bitmaps are drawn based on a `PathMeasure` object created from `mImagePath` and how far the user has dragged.

However, it's noticeable that the images do not precisely follow the expected path as the disc is "rotated".  This causes problems, as the images need to align accurately to the edge of the disc.

For troubleshooting, I started drawing `mImagePath` using `canvas.drawPath(mImagePath, strokePaint)`) to see why the image path didn't seem to follow the disc path.

In the screenshot below, to make the problem more obvious, the regular bitmaps are not drawn on top of the disc, and `mImagePath` was translated downwards by 4dp (i.e. the problem is also visible when not translated).

[image: Three instances of the custom disc View]

Here we can see three independent instances of the custom View stacked on top of one another.

But it's clear that the black line (`mImagePath`) does not match the radius of the top of the coloured disc (`mDiscPath`) in each case.  i.e. The radius of the black arc appears to be large than the disc's radius.

The arcs for both `Path` objects were created using the same bounding box, so I would expect both arcs to have the same radius.

The line on the bottom disc seems to match up well, but the top two discs are clearly wrong.
The only real difference between the discs is the number of images displayed, and therefore the sweep angle of the image path (89°, 169°, 222° respectively for the three views).

---

### Question

Why, if the exact same square `RectF` bounding box is being used to create two `Path` objects, why do arcs drawn from these Paths have different radii?

Am I missing something?  Should I be using a different API?

---

#### Postscript

I've ensured the bounding box is correctly sized and doesn't change between creating the two paths.
The start and sweep angles look correct in all cases (i.e. the midpoint of each arc is at 270°).
Creating brand new Paths or resetting the existing Paths makes no difference.
Using the same arc sweep for both Paths does work as expected.
I've tested on various devices and orientations, with and without software rendering.

Comment: Where are you determining the view's dimensions? Are you specifying `mDiscPath` and `mImagePath` together? What happens if you provide the same path with different Paints?

Comment: Both code fragments above live together in the same method, which is called with width and height from `onSizeChanged()` (if width > 0 && height > 0). Using the same path with different Paints works in theory. But as `mImagePath` is much bigger than the visible area of the View (the bounds will be like 3000x3000), I can't paint it without getting "Path too large to be rendered into a texture" errors.

Comment: That's how I would do it, and eliminates any layout passes as part of your problem. I'm really stumped on this one as well. All that really comes to mind is possibly some rounding problems in `halfWidth`. Perhaps to eradicate any differences between the arcs, you can take an entirely different approach and use `canvas.scale()` to draw the entire arc, but with a transformed graphics state?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem?

Comment: I got the info in the G+ thread that a curve can be flattened when using the same bounding box but different arc lengths. But I didn't get a chance to come up with another solution, so the "fix" so far was to make some small drawing/graphic tweaks to minimise the visibility of this problem. https://plus.google.com/103712615773524578393/posts/St3CfvdCBq2